# Mathematica Help: FullSimplify does not use conjugate identities

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, expression, simplify, complex-numbers

FullSimplify fails to recognize that:

```
 a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a] = 2 Re[a*b]
```

I have some very complex equations that could be simplified greatly if Mathematica could recognize this simple identity

```
(and that a*Conjugate[b] - b*Conjugate[a] = 2 Im[a*b]).
```

See, Mathematica will not finish solving my equations when written in

```
a*Conjugate[b] +b*Conjugate[a] form,
```

but I could at the very least write my final equations in an extremely descriptive and compact form if Mathematica recognized this. The actual expressions look like:

```
-((I q1 + q2)/(I q0 + Sqrt[-q0^2 + q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2])) -
 (Conjugate[q1] + I Conjugate[q2])/
 (Conjugate[q0] + I Conjugate[Sqrt[-q0^2 + q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2]])
```

I would do this myself, but there are 16 of such expressions and they form 4 sets of coupled systems. Since one sign error would render my work useless, I would strongly prefer an automated process.

Answer (score 4):

The identity you gave, `b Conjugate[a] + a Conjugate[b] == 2 Re[a b]`, is only true if at least one of a and b is real:

```
In[7]:= Simplify[
 Reduce[a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a] == 2 Re[a*b], {a, b}]]

Out[7]= Im[a] == 0 || Im[b] == 0
```

If this additional condition is in fact true in your application then you could give it to  Simplify or FullSimplify as an assumption, as their second argument. For example:

```
In[14]:= FullSimplify[Im[a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a]], 
 Im[a] == 0 || Im[b] == 0]

Out[14]= 0
```

By the way, here is one example when the identity is not true:

```
In[1]:= FindInstance[
 a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a] != 2 Re[a*b], {a, b}]

Out[1]= {{a -> -I, b -> -I}}
```

Comment: In M'ma 7, I've found that Assuming[{...}, _sequence_of_simplification_functions [ _stuff_ ] ] is much less annoying that passing assumptions in to each of the simplification functions.  (And substantially less prone to cut/paste errors.)

Answer (score 1):

First pass:  Use ComplexExpand[].

```
    In := Simplify[ ComplexExpand[ a Conjugate[b] + b Conjugate[a], {a, b} ] ]
    Out = 2 (Im[a] Im[b] + Re[a] Re[b])
```

For more fun, look at ComplexityFunction, although I find that a lot of trial and error is involved in tuning FullSimplify.

Comment: Be careful with ComplexExpand. As explained in its documentation (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html), it explicitly assumes that all variables are real. This is often very useful, but it is not a correct assumption in this case.

Comment: @Andrew Moylan: While true, the second argument to ComplexExpand is a list of symbols to be treated as Complex.  Thus the {a,b}, above.

Comment: Ah quite right, my mistake. I didn't read your post carefully enough, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct identity should be:

```
a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a] == 2 Re[Conjugate[a]*b]
```

It's always true:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a] == 2 Re[Conjugate[a]*b]]

Out[1]= True
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your identity correct? I'm getting different numbers for two sides

```
{a*Conjugate[b] + b*Conjugate[a], 2 Re[a*b]} /. {a -> RandomComplex[],b -> RandomComplex[]}
```